# syslog-ng revice json string

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

Now I used syslog-ng recive json-format log and store to local file, but the log was be changed.

pro log:

```
{"input_name":"sensor_alert","machine":"10.200.249.27"}
```

currently store log:

```
"sensor_alert","machine":"10.200.249.27"}`
```

the key "input_name" was be deleted

syslog-ng config:

```
    source test_src {
        udp(
            ip(0.0.0.0) port(5115)
        );
    };


    destination test_dest {
        file("/data/test_${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}.log"
            template("$MSG\n")
            template-escape(no));
    };

    log {
        source(test_src);
        destination(test_dest);
    };
```

Who can tell me the reason, thks.

Answer (score 0):

If you only send the above mentioned string (without any other framing) probably you should turn of parsing in the source with:

```
udp(... flags(no-parse));
```

This is going to put everything it received into the MSG macro.

If you have some kind of framing (like syslog) please provide an sample message, because otherwise I can only guess.